# How to add an Employee Number to my print statement?

Tags: java, arrays, string, double, pastebin

```
import java.util.*;  
import java.util.Arrays;
public class EmployeeWeeklyHours{    

      public static void main(String[] args) {    

               int[][] employeeHours= new int[][] {      
                   { 2, 4, 3, 4, 5, 8, 8},      
                   { 7, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4},      
                   { 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2},      
                   { 9, 3, 4, 7, 3, 4, 1},      
                   { 3, 5, 4, 3, 6, 3, 8},      
                   { 3, 4, 4, 6, 3, 4, 4},      
                   { 3, 7, 4, 8, 3, 8, 4},      
                   { 6, 3, 5, 9, 2, 7, 9}};  

               int [] finalHours = new int[8];  

               for (int i = 0; i < finalHours.length; i++) {   
                   int total = 0;  
                   for (int j = 0; j < finalHours.length - 1; j++) {  
                       total += employeeHours[i][j];  
                       finalHours[i] = total;  
                   }
               }

               java.util.Arrays.sort(finalHours);

               int[] sort = new int[finalHours.length];

               for (int i = 0; i < finalHours.length; i++) 
                   sort[i] = finalHours[i];        
               for (int i = 7; i > -1; i--) 
                   System.out.println(sort[i]);
      }
}
```

Employee  0:   2   4   3   4   5   8   8
Employee  1:   7   3   4   3   3   4   4
Employee  2:   3   3   4   3   3   2   2
Employee  3:   9   3   4   7   3   4   1
Employee  4:   3   5   4   3   6   3   8
Employee  5:   3   4   4   6   3   4   4
Employee  6:   3   7   4   8   3   8   4
Employee  7:   6   3   5   9   2   7   9

As you can see from my code, I am supposed to list the total hours worked for each employee in descending order.  However, I seem to be stumped on a way to show the Employee Numbers next to their total hours.

E.G. "Employee 7 worked 42 hours.

Is there any way that I can list the Employee Numbers alongside the sorted numbers without hard coding them in? I feel like there is a simple answer to my question, but nothing comes to mind right now.

Comment: Please post pertinent code, preferably a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), here with your question, not in a link. Links can go dead, and links may hold large programs, programs too large to ask a volunteer to review. Your compliance with this request will be greatly appreciated and will likely help you in getting better and faster help.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of posting your code for you.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels do you think we really need class name or confirmation that this code is in `main` method? If no then can you tell me why did you rolled back my edit? (I am not saying you shouldn't, I am just curious why do you think code example is better in current form).

Comment: The one thing that makes it a bit more difficult is that array sort. If you could make a method to manually sort the array, then you could simply use 'i' to name an employee and mimic the employee sort with the hours sort.

Comment: @Pshemo: because in its current form it, it complies with the mcve standard and can be copied and pasted into any IDE and compiled, run, modified and tested. Why change it so that we can't do this?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Tanks for answering. Just to explain myself: I like simplicity in examples which is why I often remove unneeded information (like class name, and often location of code especially when code is long and we need to scroll it to see it fully). I also have project/class which I simply update with code examples from questions so pasting fragment to main is not big problem for me (and I kind of assumed that also for others). But I see your point and agree that full example has its pros which is why I don't mind your rollback. Again thanks for comment :)

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be using a TreeMap since it sorts on the keys automatically.

```
TreeMap<Integer, Integer> treeMap = 
              new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>(Collections.reverseOrder());
for (int i = 0; i < finalHours.length; i++) {
    treeMap.put(finalHours[i], i);
}

for (Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : treeMap.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println( "Employee " + entry.getValue() + " worked " + entry.getKey() + " hours.");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for (int i=0; i < finalHours.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(String.format("Employee %d worked %d hours.", i, finalHours[i]));
}
```

And since you mentioned hardcoding, when you write a loop, rather than putting a magic "7" in there, use variables like `finalHours.length` or `employeeHours.length`. The same principle holds in general: refer to variables even when you "know" what the value is going to be.

Answer (score -2):

if you want this code ?

```
import java.util.*;  
import java.util.Arrays;
public class EmployeeWeeklyHours{    

      public static void main(String[] args) {    

               int[][] employeeHours= new int[][]{      
               { 2, 4, 3, 4, 5, 8, 8},      
               { 7, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4},      
               { 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2},      
               { 9, 3, 4, 7, 3, 4, 1},      
               { 3, 5, 4, 3, 6, 3, 8},      
               { 3, 4, 4, 6, 3, 4, 4},      
               { 3, 7, 4, 8, 3, 8, 4},      
               { 6, 3, 5, 9, 2, 7, 9}};  

               String [] finalHours = new String[8];  

               for (int i = 0; i < finalHours.length; i++) 
               {   
                   int total = 0;  
                   for (int j = 0; j < finalHours.length-1; j++) 
                   {  

                       total += employeeHours[i][j];  
                       finalHours[i] = "Employee "+ i+" worked "+total + "hours";
                   }

               }

               java.util.Arrays.sort(finalHours);

               String[] sort = new String[finalHours.length];
               for (int i = 0; i < finalHours.length; i++) 
               {  
                   sort[i] = finalHours[i];  
               }

               for (int i = 7; i > -1; i--) 
               { 
                   System.out.println(sort[i]);
               }

      }
}
```

result is

```
Employee 7 worked 41hours
Employee 6 worked 37hours
Employee 5 worked 28hours
Employee 4 worked 32hours
Employee 3 worked 31hours
Employee 2 worked 20hours
Employee 1 worked 28hours
Employee 0 worked 34hours
```

use int[] alternative String[] so you can obatin that result.
bye.

Comment: To quote the question: "I am supposed to list the total hours worked for each employee in descending order."